# Vuetify how to improve advance grid rendering

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

In my Vuetifyjs projects, we use pretty advanced data grids. Advanced in a sense of, it has buttons and menu items. Something is bothering me a bit in the rendering performance for the grids which contains buttons and menu items. In some cases it takes up to 700ms to render the advance grids with about 40-50 records.

**Question**: What can I do to improve rendering speed?

**Known Solution**: Obvious solution is to have 10 records per page, but for now that is last resort

**Side Note**: Normal grids with no buttons and menus items performance is **fine**

Take a look at my [codepen example](https://codepen.io/Jubels/pen/wNywdO?&editable=true&editors=101). Its still pretty simple and you can cleary see the slow rendering when clearing the data en show it again.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    Total Records: {{desserts.length}}
    <v-btn @click="cleanData()">Clean Data</v-btn>
    <v-btn @click="resetData()">Reset Data</v-btn>
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" class="elevation-1" hide-actions>
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">
          <v-menu bottom origin="center center" transition="scale-transition" offset-y>
          <v-btn color="secondary" medium slot="activator">
            <v-icon>more_horiz</v-icon>
          </v-btn>

          <v-list>
            <v-list-tile v-for="item in menuItems" :key="item">
              <v-list-tile-title>{{ item }}</v-list-tile-title>
            </v-list-tile>
          </v-list>
          </v-menu>

          <v-tooltip top>
                                        <v-btn
                                            color="success"
                                            slot="activator"
                                            medium
                                            @click.stop="
                                            "
                                        >
                                            <v-icon>arrow_forward</v-icon>
                                        </v-btn>
                                        <span>Move to next status</span>
                                    </v-tooltip>
        </td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Found something? Having a similar issue.